# FullCalendar - Unselect Date(s) from Date(s) Selection Before Adding Event(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Within month view only, i'm wanting to allow a user to select a number of dates, either a range or individual, as well as allow them to **unselect** dates from within that selection (ie - holding shift/ctrl whilst clicking a date) before they click an 'Add' button and adding events to those days.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManCalledDom/1t8kjamj/)

Because i'm wanting to allow for multiple selections, i've gone down the route of adding a 'background' rendering eventsource to the calendar upon selection (using the Select callback) and giving the eventsource the same id 'newEvent'.

First problem, i'm unable to to remove this eventsource nor get the dates of the source using the id and the following -

```
fullCalendar('removeEventSources', 'newEvent');
fullCalendar('getEventSourceById', 'newEvent');
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Secondly, with regards to de-selecting dates from the selection, am i right in thinking i'd use the 'dayClick' callback and remove that date from the create eventsource?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Alternatively, is there is a better method of doing this within FullCalendar?